# Refactoring regular expression needed

Tags: regex

Can you please help me with a regular expression that I need for some code refactoring? I am trying to change the following

```
    something a.executeQuery() something else
    something b.executeQuery() something else
    something c.executeQuery() something else
```

to

```
    something someClass.executeQueryEx(a) something else
    something someClass.executeQueryEx(b) something else
    something someClass.executeQueryEx(c) something else
```

Basically trying to bring all DB calls to a central function, so that I can log them and do error handling at one place.

Comment: Is this in .NET? What constraints are there on the values you've illustrated with `a`, `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a,b,c are just identifiers, you can simply replace

```
 (\w+)\.executeQuery\(\)
```

with

```
 someClass.executeQueryEx(\1)
```

or

```
 someClass.executeQueryEx($1)
```

depending on your regex engine.

If they can be arbitrary expressions, as in `foo(quux).bar[25].executeQuery()` I don't think you can do that with regexes alone.

Comment: If it's a .NET regex environment, s/\1/$1/ in your replacement.

Comment: Thanks georg. They are simple identifiers. Your expression works for me.